# Ошибка созданя дополнения VSTO уровня документа (V2)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, office, vsto

Здравствуйте. Подскажите пожалуйста. Впервые имею дело с надстройками VSTO для Excel уровня документа, пробую создать проект для Excel шаблона уровня документа и получаю ошибку со следующими словами:

> Невозможно создать проект

По справке буквально два слова написано. Никаких других документов не открыто. Модель VBA разрешена, что еще не учла? Спасайте, горю, пожалуйста. VS2015 Community, Office 2016. Совсем печалька одолела. Я даже проект создать не могу.

Comment: У Вас и проект надстройки для Office 2016 и версия Office  установленная на Вашем компьютере также 2016 они соответствуют друг другу?

Comment: да, офис 2016 64x, шаблоны в VS2015comm тоже для 2016 и 2013 написано